# Set value in html fields in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular 4 project I have to set some value in input field and in a MatSelect without any binding.

This is the HTML

```
<div class="row search-component">
    <div class="col-md-5 no-padding-right">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select placeholder="searchfor" id="selectedFilter" name="propertyList" #selectedFilter>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let property of propertyList" [value]="property">
                    {{property.label}} </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7 no-padding-left">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="search" id="searchfield" name="searchfield" #selectedValue>
            <mat-icon class="pointer" matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click in a button I have to set a Mat-option and a value in the input field.

This is the method Who have to set the values:

```
 setField(chipSelected: Filter) {
    this.filter = chipSelected;
    document.getElementById('searchfield').focus();
    document.getElementById('searchfield').value = 'somevalue'; <-- I can't use this instruction
  }
```

I can't access to value, Why?
And how can I access to it?

Comment: where are you writing this method in ts file ??

Comment: updated my answer have a look , that how you can access element ..

Answer (score 6):

you can access input element as below

```
<input #someInput placeholder="test input">

import { AfterViewInit,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('someInput') someInput: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.someInput.nativeElement.value = "update input value";
  }
}
```

---

its angular, then you just bind you input with the template property and assign value

```
  <input matInput [(ngModel)] = "searchFor" placeholder="search" 
      id="searchfield" name="searchfield" #selectedValue>
```

then in ts file jus do like this

```
setField(chipSelected: Filter) {
///your code
 this.searchFor='somevalue';
}
```

I am not geting one thing you are making use of angularjs2 and typescript and you are trying to get element value by  `document.getElementById`, is something wrong ??

because Component comes with template and .ts template code file ..and you achieve this functionality easily.

Comment: I know ngModel , but I don't have to use it in this case

Comment: @Alessandro - if you do like this than dont make use of angular js 2, because template concept introduced for seperation of concern means to keep html and js in diffrent file ...and by this way you are exposing your html to js file which is wrong pattern, this is written on angular.io website

Comment: @Alessandro - please do accept/uvpvote if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, I guess that you are new in Angular world. I suggest you to read something about `ngModel` and data binding in angular ([here a link](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#two-way-binding)). Using native JS methods like `.getElementId()` is a horrible idea. F.e. the better solution is use ngModel for your input in way:

```
<input matInput placeholder="search" [(ngModel)]="someValue" id="searchfield" name="searchfield">
```

declare cariable in your component:

```
someValue: string;
```

and in your method use:

```
setField(chipSelected: Filter) {
    this.someValue = 'somevalue';
}
```

Comment: I know ngModel , but I don't have to use it in this case

Comment: I edited my post. I added link to official tutorial/documentation to use ngModel too.

Comment: seems like OP trying something out of box or may be want to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @PranayRana I know that NgModel is a best practice but I ask to do it without it, if you don't know how to do it without NgModel please don't answer

Comment: @Alessandro- i sussgest you another way , which is Reactive form approch ..in that you can get access to element